# Is external_pid_file of PostgreSQL checked for shut down?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Question about `external_pid_file` configuration option of PostgreSQL: would the additional PID file be checked for shut down instead of `postmaster.pid`?

What I could find is:

```
# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.4-main.pid'          # write an extra PID file
```

Usually, if `postmaster.pid` becomes corrupt or is removed, the server shuts down with

```
performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
```

Thus the above question about the behaviour. Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external PID file is not used for anything.  It's just there so that if someone wants a PID file in, say, `/var/run/`, they can do that easily.  But if you remove that external PID file while the PostgreSQL server is running, you won't get the immediate shutdown behavior.